# Does rel='alternate' have to show protocol

Tags: rel-alternate

I'm using rel='alternate' like this:

> http://example.com/_spanish/index.htm'
>   hreflang='es'

Is it acceptable to leave out the HTTP protocol and use

link rel='alternate' href='//example.com/_spanish/index.htm' hreflang='es'

Thank you